# sql top N value

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How can I make a SQL query and have a parameter the top N value. For example the first person wants to see the top 10 values, the next perhaps the top 50, maybe the top 100. Would I say something like SELECT TOP =@Value from Table?

Thanks

Yes this is for SQL Server. Standard Query, showing everything, but id like to limit the number of rows returned based on input from the user.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SELECT    TOP(cast(@N as integer)) COLUMN1 ,Column2 from table1

That works...

Comment: +1 Note that the syntax will be different in different flavours of SQL (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) - this looks like SQLServer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the top clause?  If your using MySQL you can just use LIMIT to restrict the number of results.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is in regards to SQL Server.

You can use set rowcount.

Check out details on how to use this on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to restrict it by ROW_NUMBER in the WHERE clause.